# What is "the star" communicating in Synaptic?

Tags: synaptic

A star sometimes appears next to things in the Synaptic list. What is the star there for? What is it telling me?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are "new" packages there weren't in the list of available packages the last time you run Synaptic.

You can also see them in the *New in repository* filter in the *Status* view:

[image]